# Get all objects of a certain 'prototype' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have recently started messing about with JavaScript and building my own jQuery plugins and have stumbled on a problem when using prototypes (something I still don't quite understand but starting to get the gist of it). I have done a fairly detailed search for my problem and couldn't find anything so apologies if this is a dupe.

When the DOM loads I have it cycling through a set of elements and creates new `MyObject` objects out of these elements with functions defined in `MyObject.prototype`. Is it possible that in the console or a later time I could go through and retrieve all objects of the `MyObject` type?

Sorry if my descriptions don't make much sense I am new to the JavaScript world and the terminology escapes me a little.

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602800/how-to-get-all-objects-of-a-given-type-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: You can build your `MyObject` object to register every newly created instance in some globally accessible array/list (which will complicate garbage collection), but other than that, the language doesn't provide a feature to give you a list of all objects of a specific type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a register of `MyObject`s and referencing that just as [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) suggested in a comment to the question and it is working perfectly, thanks a heap!