# Loop through each new Object from Constructor

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Firstly, sorry for my lack of terminology.

If I have a constructor

```
function myObject(name, value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}
```

and I make a few objects from it

```
var One = new myObject("One", 1);
var Two = new myObject("Two", 2);
```

Can I loop through each new Object made from the `myObject` class, without putting each new Object into an Array?

---

would it be possible to add an Instantly Invoking Function to the constructor that adds the Object into an array?

e.g.

```
function myObject(name, value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;

    this.addToArray = function(){
        theArray.push(this);        // this is the IIFE
    }(); 
}
```

that way any new objects created instantly run this function and get added to the array.

Is this possible? ( current syntax does not work, obviously )

---

*EDIT* Coming back to this one year later I can tell you that it IS possible. You just call the function inside the constructor like so:

```
function myObject(name, value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;

    this.addToArray = function(){
        theArray.push(this);
    };

    this.addToArray();

}
```

Here is an example of this in JSFIDDLE, pushing each object into an array on instantiation and then calling each object's `.speak()` method directly from the array.

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/8bpmrso1/

Comment: Is Object.keys(One); what you need?

Comment: You can't, nothing keep a reference to your objects.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to See each Object that I have created from the  myObject Constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602800/how-to-get-all-objects-of-a-given-type-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using an array, you can't, it is not the way it is meant to be used.

What you can do though, is watch over each instances created in a static member of `myObject` class

```
function myObject(name, value){
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;

    this.watch();
}

myObject.prototype.watch = function () {
    if (myObject.instances.indexOf(this) === -1) {
        myObject.instances.push(this);
    }
};

myObject.prototype.unwatch = function () {
    myObject.instances.splice(myObject.instances.indexOf(this), 1);
};

myObject.instances = [];
```

Comment: Will they not exist somewhere in the window.?

Comment: @JoshStevenson only globals.

Comment: See my edit, is it possible this way? I feel like this should be something that is easy to achieve however it's proving not to be!

Comment: @JoshStevenson Your edit with the IIFE is redundant, it is basically the same as doing directly `theArray.push(this)`, plus `this.addToArray` will be `undefined` as you don't return anything from the IIFE.

Comment: I know. that's why I said " current syntax does not work, obviously"

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. You cannot do this with almost all programming languages.

You can, in the constructor, store a reference of every object you created into an array/map so that you can iterate over them any time. This, however, prevents all objects of this class from being garbage collected, so use it with care.

The `WeakMap` in JavaScript keeps only a week reference to the keys, but it, in turn, does not allow you to loop over all keys. So it is not an option either.

Comment: If you were really determined that you wanted to do this, then you could keep an array of the WeakMap's keys and loop over that.

Comment: Then this extra array will retain the objects, defeating the whole purpose of `WeakMap`. The reason I mentioned the `WeakMap` solution because this is how you would achieve the same with programming languages that support a true weak map that you can iterate over.

Comment: See my edit, is it possible this way? I feel like this should be something that is easy to achieve however it's proving not to be!

Answer (score 0):

```
var MyClass = (function() {
  var _instances = [];

  function MyClass(name, value) {
    _instances.push(this);

    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  MyClass.each = function(cb) {
    for (var i in _instances) {
      if (_instances.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        cb(_instances[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return MyClass;

})();

new MyClass('John', 10);
new MyClass('James', 20);

MyClass.each(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```