# JavaScript - Get all objects that are instances of a specific class

Tags: javascript

I am not sure it is possible but I will try my luck.

Is it possible in JavaScript to find all objects that are instances of a specific class?

For example:

```
var obj1 = new MyClass();
var obj2 = new MyClass();
var obj3 = new MyClass();
```

I want to specify the class name "MyClass" and to **get "obj1,obj2,obj3" in response**.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get all objects of a given type in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602800/how-to-get-all-objects-of-a-given-type-in-javascript)

Comment: Create an array and push the instances into it. `MyClass.allInstances = []; MyClass.allInstances.push(this);` Just be careful to remove these at some point or you will have issues with memory when a lot of objects are created

Comment: What if MyClass is 3rd party library and I dont have access to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all instances of class in jquery or js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526456/get-all-instances-of-class-in-jquery-or-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
function MyClass(){};

MyClass.prototype.test = function(){
   console.log('TEST');
};

function MyClassFactory(){
  this.instances = [];
};

MyClassFactory.prototype.create = function(){
  let tmp = new MyClass();
  this.instances.push(tmp);
  return tmp;
};

MyClassFactory.prototype.get = function(i){
  return this.instances[i];
};

MyClassFactory.prototype.getAll = function(){
  return this.instances;
};

let factory = new MyClassFactory();

let obj1 = factory.create();
let obj2 = factory.create();
let obj3 = factory.create();

let test1 = factory.get(0);

let test2 = factory.getAll();

for(let t of test2){
  t.test();
}

test1.test();
```

Comment: What if MyClass is 3rd party library and I dont have access to it?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just write the factory-code. The only thing you have to change in the example is the create method. There you have to add parameters that you need to initialize the objects properly.

Comment: Would be nice if you could tell everybody the 3rd party library you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this doesn't work. You could save your objects in an array and iterate over it to retrieve all objects of class `MyClass`.

```
var objects = [new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass()];
function getObjectsOfClass(objects, clazz) {
   var objArr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
       if (objects[i] instanceof clazz) {
           objArr.push(objects[i];
       }
   }
   return objArr;
}
```

Comment: What if MyClass is 3rd party library and I dont have access to it?

Comment: You always need access to the class. How else should the class be instantiated? Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602800/how-to-get-all-objects-of-a-given-type-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1) is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this situation.

```
function M(){}
var m = new M();
```

Then you van do something like

```
for(let f in window){ if(window[f] instanceof M){console.log("founded"+f);}}
```

And you will find your object.

Hope that helps

Comment: What if the objects are instantiated outside the global scope?

Comment: Obviously, It won't work. That was an example. However, you can create a function accepting a scope as a parameter.

Comment: I feel like this would be very expensive to perform. Is it fair practice to iterate over the Window object like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only if you made some modification to the constructor

example:

```
var MyClassInstances = [];
var MyClass = function() { //constructor
   MyClassInstances.push(this); //push the new instance
}
```

thats it!. But be aware that it might become memory leak. so, you have to remove the reference from MyClassInstances when the objects are not needed.

Comment: What if MyClass is 3rd party library and I dont have access to it?