# Display Object in Html - Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I display film1, film2 and film3 in the HTML?
I tried

```
peliHtml.innerHTML = `${this.Film.title};
```

but I'm getting a console error. How could I display that data in the html?

**HTML**

```
<p id="films"></p>
```

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
class Film {
    title = '';
    director = '';
    genre = '';
    date = '';
    getDates(){
        return `marca: ${this.title} - director: ${this.director}, genre: ${this.genre}, date: ${this.date}`;
    };

    constructor(title, director, genre, fechaEstreno){
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.date = date;
    }

}

let film1 = new Film('El hobbit', 'peter jackson', 'aventura', '23-02-2002');
let film2 = new Film('El hobbit 2', 'peter jackson', 'aventura', '23-02-2010');
let film3 = new Film('El hobbit 3', 'peter jackson', 'aventura', '23-02-2020');


const peliHtml = document.getElementById('films');
peliHtml.innerHTML = `${this.Film.title}`;
```

Comment: you need `film1.title` (or whichever film whos title you actually want to display)

Comment: Not sure whether you are looking for this, but see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824721/javascript-get-all-objects-that-are-instances-of-a-specific-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` only refers to a `Film` object within the `Film` class. As a general rule of thumb: don't use `this` outside of a class.

If you want to display all the names of the films, it'd be better to put all the `Film` objects in an array, use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `.title` attribute for each`, then join each element with a comma:

```js
class Film {
  title = '';
  director = '';
  genre = '';
  date = '';
  getDates() {
    return `marca: ${this.title} - director: ${this.director}, genre: ${this.genre}, date: ${this.date}`;
  };

  constructor(title, director, genre, date) {
    this.title = title;
    this.director = director;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.date = date;
  }
}

let film1 = new Film('El hobbit', 'peter jackson', 'aventura', '23-02-2002');
let film2 = new Film('El hobbit 2', 'peter jackson', 'aventura', '23-02-2010');
let film3 = new Film('El hobbit 3', 'peter jackson', 'aventura', '23-02-2020');
const films = [film1, film2, film3];

const peliHtml = document.getElementById('films');
peliHtml.innerHTML = films.map(film => film.title).join(', ');
```

```html
<p id="films"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! that what I was need it to do, I just had to wrap it in ${},  peliHtml.innerHTML = `${ films.map(film => film.title).join(', ') }`;