# Is there a way of getting all strings loaded on a pge?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm crawling websites using Puppeteer, and am performing some tasks on each page. I'm looking for a way of listing all strings contained within the loaded javascript. I'm guessing such a task isn't possible (without parsing all of the javascript). But if anyone knows how, I'd be very curious.

Comment: are you trying to parse a Javascript code or state of the page?

Comment: Not trying to parse the javascript. I'd be executing my javascript within the context of a page with scripts loaded on it.

Comment: My bad, but you're trying to get all the string from the page is what you meant?

Comment: Exactly. So if there's a script loaded on the page, with many variables defined, then I'd like to list all of the variable's values which are strings. Something like this... 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602834/2693030
But this only works for global variables.